# calculations in a rdlc report

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reporting

Using VS 2010 win forms project. I have a winform fo a workorder entry screen. At the bottom of the workorder form are a few calculated textboxes that are calculated from functions in a class.

I have created a rdlc report to print the workorder but now I need to use those functions to represent the calculations to total the workorder, taxes, fees etc.

Can I use the functions by passing them as variables? What is the best way to get these function results on to the report?

Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you pass only the value calculated by your functions to the RDLC file? You can use `Report Parameters` to pass the value to the file.

[ReportParameter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportparameter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And [here you can find](http://www.gotreportviewer.com/localmodeparameters/index.html) a little example to use them

Btw the code will look like this:

```
//Click to generate the report
ReportParameter p1 = new ReportParameter("NameOfFirstParameter", valueReturningFromYourFunction);
ReportParameter p2 = new ReportParameter("NameOfSecondParameter", valueReturningFromYourFunction);
localReport.SetParameters(p1);
localReport.SetParameters(p2);
localReport.Render(...);
```

Comment: Cool, I will look into it. Makes sense! I will post back with an answer as to how it works.